# Get longest name in list of names python

Tags: python, python-3.x

An example be like:

```
def get_longest_name(a_list):
    count = 0
    for i in a_list:
        if len(i) > count: 
           count = len(i)
           word = i
    return word
def main():
    print("1.", get_longest_name(["Candide", "Jessie", "Kath", "Amity", 
   "Raeanne"]))
    print("2.", get_longest_name(["Josephine", "Jessie", "Penelope", "Jin", 
  "Rosamunda", "Annabelle"]))
    print("3.", get_longest_name(["Alan", "Jess", "Amity", "Rosalie", 
  "Raeanne"]))
    print("4. ", "***", get_longest_name(["Jo", "Jai", "Jen", "Jing", "Joey", 
   "Jess"]), "***", sep = "")
    print("5. ", "***", get_longest_name([]), "***", sep = "")
    print("6.", "***" + get_longest_name([""]) + "***")
main()
```

output like:

```
1. Candide
2. Josephine
3. Rosalie
4. ***Jing***
```

I already get three correct output(three longest names).The function should returns the word in the list which has the most characters (the longest word) BUT only words with six or more characters are considered.  If two or more words in the list have the same number of characters as the longest word, the function should return the first word from the start of the list which has the most characters.  If the parameter list is empty or if there are no words in the list with six of more characters, the function should return the empty string. so output be like:

```
 1. Candide
 2. Josephine
 3. Rosalie
 4. ******
 5. ******
 6. ******
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this additional problems so far?

Comment: BTW, that code will raise `NameError` if `a_list` is empty, or doesn't contain any words that pass the `if` test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `max()` with `key=len`:

```
def get_longest_name(a_list, min_length=6):
    return max((name for name in a_list if len(name) >= min_length), key=len, default='')
```

A generator expression processes `a_list` to include only those names of length >= 6.

Comment: @Moses: thanks for the edit.

Comment: FWIW, in Python 3, `max` accepts a `default` arg which it returns if you pass it an empty iterable.

Comment: @PM2Ring: thanks, didn't know about the `default` argument. Included that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @mhawke solution:

```
def get_longest_name(a_list, min_length=6):
    longest = max(a_list, key=len) if a_list else ''
    return longest if longest and len(longest) >= min_length else ''
```